# Absolute imports issue in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I've been wandering through posts and posts about this and haven't been able to fix it. They all state pretty much the same: take notice of tsconfig.json's nesting, correctly set the baseUrl and explicitely mention filenames if were using index files. But I can't get my path aliases to work.

As I'm refactoring this project, this is getting necessary as the previous developer's dot-dot-dash hell is driving me crazy.

An excerpt from my project's structure:

```
.
+-- tsconfig.js
+-- package.json
+-- src
|   +-- ui
|   |   +-- hooks
|   |   |   +-- useProfessionalOnboarding
|   |   |   |   +-- index.tsx
|   |   +-- components
|   |   |   +-- professional
|   |   |   |   +-- onboarding
|   |   |   |   |   +-- availability
|   |   |   |   |   |   +-- ProOboardingServicesAvailability.tsx
|   |   +-- pages
|   |   |   +-- ProfessionalOnBoarding
|   |   |   |   +-- ...
|   |   +-- types
|   |   |   +-- ...
|   +-- index.tsx
|   +-- App.tsx
```

Now in `ProOboardingServicesAvailability.tsx` I'm trying to import the `useProfessionalOnboarding` hook as

`import useProfessionalOnboarding from '@hooks/useProfessionalOnboarding/index';`

My tsconfig.json being

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@hooks/*": [
        "ui/hooks*"
      ],
    },

    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [ "src" ]
}
```

However I keep getting "Cannot find module or its correspondent type declarations".

I tried some other paths mappings as `"@hooks/*": [ "./ui/hooks*" ]`, `"@hooks/*": [ "src/ui/hooks*" ]` `"@hooks/*": [ "./src/ui/hooks*" ]`, none worked. Tried with and without the at-symbol, no difference.

There's a ton of work ahead and a small hideous chance of having to do the ant work of going through each file re-counting the '../'s. I crave for help. At least some way of tweaking or debugging.

btw I'm using Atom for text editor.

[image: Error message screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Do the paths at least work when you compile/run the project?

Comment: Should be `"@hooks/*": [ "ui/hooks/*"]`

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks. It's a typo in the question but not in the code, it's actually ui/hooks/* and not working

Comment: @catgirlkelly no, Module not found: Can't resolve '@hooks/useProfessionalOnboarding/index' in '[projectPath]/src/apps/application/frontend/src/ui/components/professional/onboarding/availability'. Compiles when I change to relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that a message flashed between the run startup and the compiling step. I says `compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)`! It was flashing fast and I had to take a screen capture to read it.

Looking up, I found [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8909#issuecomment-657134865) which states

> create-react-app doesn't support path aliasing and probably won't for
> the near future.

I'll settle with baseUrl